# New line in Prompt

Tags: automationanywhere

How to add a new line in automation anywhere prompts like yes/no, Enter Value

I have tried to use

```
First Line[Enter]Second Line
```

I would like to know if it's possible

Here prompt-assignment has "Prev Line" as its value.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Html string will help to provide multiline prompt.

```
<html>This is first line.<br/>This is second line.</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Wish i knew this before! Thanks :)